# Variable que recorre el for no se actualiza

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando que cuando el `for` exterior cumpla una iteración, se actualice la variable `i`, de la manera que se indica en el `if` despues del `for` interno (`if  i+self.nGroups > n`)

```
  for i in 0..n
    for j in 0..self.nGroups-1
      if i+j <= n
        puts "i=#{i} , j=#{j}"
        @competition_users[i+j].group = j+1
        puts @competition_users[i+j].group
        @competition_users[i+j].save
      end
    end
    if  i+self.nGroups > n
      i += 1
    else
      i += self.nGroups
    end
  end
```

Para los valores `n=4`, `nGroups=2`, desgraciadamente la salida de los `puts` es la siguiente:

```
     i=0 , j=0
     1
     i=0 , j=1
     2
     i=1 , j=0
     1
     i=1 , j=1
     2
     i=2 , j=0
     1
     i=2 , j=1
     2
     i=3 , j=0
     1
     i=3 , j=1
     2
     i=4 , j=0
     1
```

Cuando lo que yo espero es:

```
     i=0 , j=0
     1
     i=0 , j=1
     2
     i=2 , j=0
     1
     i=2 , j=1
     2
     i=4 , j=0
     1
```

Básicamente, el índice `i` no cambia cuando realizo `i += self.nGroups`

A ver si alguien puede explicarme por qué es, o si pueden aconsejarme hacerlo de otra manera. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que aún cuando sobre escribes `i` dentro de tu if, este se vuelve a sobre escribir al valor que sigue de la iteración, por ejemplo, considera este código:

```
for i in 0..3
  puts "i (inicio): #{i}"
  i += 2
  puts "i (+2): #{i}\n\n"
end
```

Resultado:

```
i (inicio): 0
i (+2): 2

i (inicio): 1
i (+2): 3

i (inicio): 2
i (+2): 4

i (inicio): 3
i (+2): 5
```

Podrás ver que `i` en efecto cambia después de sumarle `2`, sin embargo su valor se asigna nuevamente la inicio de la iteración.

Por lo tanto debes utilizar una variable diferente para llevar el control del ciclo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo arreglé, ya que Ruby no deja cambiar en los bucles `for` sus iteradores, por lo que no queda otra que cambiar la estructura por un `while`. Por tanto el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
 i = 0 
 while (i <= n)
  for j in 0..self.nGroups-1
    if i+j <= n
      puts "i=#{i} , j=#{j}"
      @competition_users[i+j].group = j+1
      puts @competition_users[i+j].group
      @competition_users[i+j].save
    end
  end
  if  i+self.nGroups > n
    i += 1
  else
    i += self.nGroups
  end
end
```

Y la salida es la comentada:

```
          i=0 , j=0
          1
          i=0 , j=1
          2
          i=2 , j=0
          1
          i=2 , j=1
          2
          i=4 , j=0
          1
```

Comment: Mejor al `for` definitivamente, tienes más control sobre el ciclo de esa forma.

Comment: Para acortar tu código podrías utilizar un _ternario_ en lugar del `if i+self.nGroups > n ...`; por ejemplo: `i += (i + nGroups) > n ? 1 : nGroups`

Comment: Y también podrías considerar utilizar `each` en lugar de `for`; en Ruby el uso de `for` es prácticamente nulo, lo común (e impulsado por la comunidad) es utilizar los métodos de _Enumerable_ (`each` es uno de ellos); por ejemplo, en lugar de `for j in 0..self.nGroups-1` puedes utilizar `(0..nGroups - 1).each do |j|`.

Comment: @Gerry muchas gracias por tus indicaciones, las tendré en cuenta! :)

Comment: Una pequeña corrección en mis comentarios: en lugar de `nGroups` debe ser `self.nGroups` (yo había utilizado `nGroups` para pruebas). Suerte!